# Haskell frustration with function calls

Tags: list, haskell, types, monads

Learning Haskell is killing me. If I am going to write a function that takes an array of arrays of order-able elements, and outputs the same thing, how do I do that?

I try:

```
main = testfn [[1],[2]]

testfn :: (Ord a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
testfn x = x
```

But the message I get is:

> Couldn't match expected type 'IO t0' with actual type '[[a0]]' In the
>   expression: main When checking the type of the function 'main'

Comment: Note that `[a]` is a _list_, not an _array_. The difference is quite important; haskell has both, and they have very different performance implications

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem here is that `main` must be of a type of the form `IO a` (you can see this in the error - GHC is expecting main's inferred type `[[a0]]` to match against `IO t0`). Here `main` has type `[[Int]]`. You can easily fix this by simply printing the result:

```
main = print (testfn [[1],[2]])
```

Comment: Thanks. In regards to your comment on my question, could you please show me how to do the equivalent task with a real array?

Comment: Haskell arrays are somewhat more of an advanced topic, but basically, the type would look something like `IArray a (Int, Int) => a -> a`, or `Array (Int, Int) Int -> Array (Int, Int) Int`. See http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays . If you have any further questions on this topic, please open a separate question to keep things organized.

Comment: Okay. I think I'll stick with lists. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I think when talking about Haskell and arrays, knowing about the excellent `vector` package may be immensely helpful. It's interface is much more what arrays are like in most imperative languages, and very often it's just what you need. Have a look: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9/doc/html/Data-Vector.html

Answer (score 3):

The function `main` must have type `IO a`.  You are defining main as `testfn [..]` which is of type `Ord a, Num a => [[a]]`.

What do you want the program to do?  Compare to a known solution for your ordering?

```
main = print (knownSolution == testfn [[1],[2]])
```

Or perhaps print the result?

```
main = print $ testfn [[1],[2]]
```